# Qmark in pymysql query

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymysql

I'm new to python, just moving from php5. I read about the qmark param notation to prepare a query but I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 10, in <module>
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM object WHERE otype = ?", ["user"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 130, in execute
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Is that only for sqlite connector?

```
import sys
import pymysql

try:
    connection = pymysql.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="root", passwd="pass", db="xxx")
except:
    sys.exit("Database connection error")

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM object WHERE otype = ?", "user")

for row in cursor:
   print(row)

cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Unfortunately the DB-API specification left it up to each implementer to choose the parameter. pysqlite chose the ?, and MySQLdb chose %s. Since pymsql is a drop-in replacement for MySQLdb, it also uses %s.